# Javascript system for auto clicking

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, click

There is a button to my site with below markup.

```
<input name="submit_btn" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary" value="======" type="submit">
```

I want have created a button using javascript to the page.

```
function() {
        target =  document.getElementById('captcha').parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    parent_target = target.parentElement;
    wrapper = document.createElement('tr');
    wrapper.innerHTML = '<td>';
    getOtp = document.createElement('button');
    captcha = document.getElementById('captcha');
    myBtn.id = 'myBtn';
    myBtn.type = 'button';
    myBtn.innerHTML = 'My Btn';
    myBtn.style.marginRight = '5px';
    myBtn.onClick = function() {
      document.getElementById('btn1').click();
    };

wrapper.appendChild(myBtn);
parent_target.insertBefore(wrapper, target);

}();
```

Problem: I will click to the new button and javascript system will automatically click to the existing button after certain interval.

Comment: None of this JS makes sense, where's `#captcha`? `parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    parent_target` ? What is `parent_target`? If referring to `#captcha` (which isn't in the HTML) parent's parent...we need the rest of the HTML

Comment: #captcha is the id of a input. Underneath of this input i am showing new button.